# Import CSV Files from a directory in order to seed a database on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, mongodb, csv

I need to seed a database with a lot of records from some Excel files, but I will only use those CSV files once because after seeding the database the other records will be input from forms.

My boss told me to put the CSV files in a directory in the project and then get the records from those files to the database.

I'm using MongoDB on Rails.

I don't want the full code, just some guidance with gems, logic, etc.

Comment: Most DBMs have ways of importing directly from CSV files. Why not take advantage of their built-in, pre-tested, executables rather than write your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for a one-off import, why not use something like [this nice gist](https://gist.github.com/naoty/1267124) or MongoDB's own tool, [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) (which can accept CSVs)

Answer (score 0):

You need the `CSV` library.  From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html):

```
arr_of_arrs = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")
```

This will give you a 2D array which you can process as you like.  `CSV` similar to [`IO.read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-read), but with a few extras such as header parsing.