# How to easily parse csv file to use in node.js sequelize database migration strategy?

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv, database-migration, sequelize-cli

I've got the migration strategy via sequelize-cli set up and running so the table can be constructed properly. It works using `sequelize db:migrate` and it creates the table just fine. And `sequelize db:migrate:undo` will delete the table.

I've also included code (per the [SE comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742962/add-data-in-sequelize-migration-script/29946461#29946461)) to insert a couple of records. That works too. Here's the code for all that:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, DataTypes, done) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('survey', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      state: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
      },
      age: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      race: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
      },
      gender: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
      },
      education: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
      },
      q1: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      q2: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      .
      .
      .
      q24: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      q25: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }
    }).then(function() {
      queryInterface.sequelize.query("INSERT INTO survey (state, age, race, gender, q1, q7, q24) VALUES ('Texas', 42, 'white', 'female', 5, 4, 3), ('Louisiana', 19, 'hispanic', 'male', 1, 2,5)");
      done();
    });
  },

  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('survey');
  }
};
```

But I have a CSV file with over 3000 records that needs to be used as the seed data. It's in the `db` folder and called `survey.csv`. I also have a `seeders` folder that I think was created automatically by a `sequelize init` or `sequelize migration:create`. It's currently empty.

I ***could*** use the concatenate function in Excel to create the ordered n-tuples of data to insert and just paste those 3000 lines into promise part of `up`, but that seems ridiculous.

I found [this reply for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106556/import-csv-files-from-a-directory-in-order-to-seed-a-database-on-rails/30108857#30108857), but in Rails:

> You need the CSV library. From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html):
>
> `arr_of_arrs = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")`
>
> This will give you a 2D array which you can process as you like. `CSV` 
>   similar to `IO.read`, but with a few extras such as header parsing.

It looks like there's a handful (or more) csv ***node*** packages, but golly, they're so complicated (like the simply-named [csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv)).

Is there a simpler csv parser (like the one for Rails) that I can use to facilitate the dumping of the csv into the database? Or another method that doesn't require a bazillion lines of superfluous code copied from a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

To create a seed file using Sequelize.js to seed data from a CSV file, you can follow these steps:

1. Install the necessary packages:

   npm install --save sequelize sequelize-cli mysql2 csv-parser

   This will install Sequelize, Sequelize CLI, the MySQL2 driver for Sequelize, and the CSV parser.
2. Create a Sequelize model for your table. For example, if your CSV file contains data about books, you can create a model like this:

   npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name Book --attributes title:string,author:string,year:integer

   This will create a `Book` model with `title`, `author`, and `year` attributes.
3. Run the migration to create the table in the database:

   npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
4. Create a seed file in the `seeders` directory using the Sequelize CLI

   npx sequelize-cli seed:generate --name seed-books

   This will create a new seed file in the `seeders` directory.
5. Edit the seed file to read the CSV file, parse its contents, and insert them into the database using Sequelize. Here's an example:

   const fs = require('fs');
   const csv = require('csv-parser');
   const Book = require('../models/book');

   ```
   module.exports = {
     up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
       const results = [];
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         fs.createReadStream('./data/books.csv')
           .pipe(csv())
           .on('data', (data) => {
             results.push(data);
           })
           .on('end', () => {
             Book.bulkCreate(results)
               .then(() => {
                 resolve();
               })
               .catch((error) => {
                 console.error(error);
                 reject(error);
               });
           });
       });
     },

     down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
       return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Books', null, {});
     },
   };
   ```

   This code reads the CSV file from the `./data/books.csv` location, parses its contents using the `csv-parser` package, and inserts the data into the `Book` table using the `bulkCreate` method of Sequelize. The `up` function is used to insert the data into the database, and the `down` function is used to delete the data if needed.
6. Run the seed to insert the data into the database:

   npx sequelize-cli db:seed --seed seeders/seed-books.js

   This will run the `up` function of the `seed-books` seed file and insert the data into the database.
7. Test the data by querying the database to ensure that the data from the CSV file was inserted correctly.

   Note: In this example, I assume that the CSV file is located in a `data` directory at the root of your project. You'll need to adjust the file path as needed for your own project.